# What day(s) of the week cannot be the first day of a century non leap-year that is a perfect square?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

This question is from contest our in school:

> What day(s) of the week cannot be the first day of a century non-leap year that is a perfect square year?

**My attempt**

A Century year is a non-leap year only if not divisible by $400$.

The first day of the century years that are not leap years are Friday, Wednesday, and Monday.

- If the century year is $100\pmod{400}$, then January $1$ will fall on a Friday. The next century year such like that will be on $2100$, and after that on $2500$, which is a perfect square year.
- If the century year is $200\pmod{400}$, January $1$ is on  Wednesday. The next century year similar to that is on $2200$. There are no century non-leap years starting on Wednesday that is a perfect square.
- If the century year is $300\pmod{400}$, then January $1$ of that year is Monday. The next century year like that is on $2300$. Again, there aren’t any century non-leap years starting on Monday that is a perfect square.

The choices given are:

> A.) Monday and Thursday

> B.) Friday and Saturday

> C.) Monday and Wednesday

> D.) Sunday and Tuesday

This is where I stuck. I tried my best, but I don’t know what is the correct answer in the choices. I think the answer is C, but I don’t know how to prove that.

Can someone help me to some this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your analysis is correct, then the only day it can be is Friday, so the only answer that is wrong is B – all the others are equally correct.

Comment: The analysis correct, provided Google did not err when providing the weekeday of January 1st, 1700, 1800 and 1900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's here overlooks the "square" condition. See the comments.

In $400$ years, there will be $97$ leap years (there are $400\div4=100$ years divisible by four, but three of these will not be leap years, namely, the ones that are multiples of $100$ but not of $400$), so $97+(400)(365)=146097=20871\times7$ days, that is, a whole number of weeks, with no days left over. So the pattern of days of the week repeats exactly every $400$ years, and we only need to look at one $400$-year cycle to answer the question.

Today is Wednesday $2$ August $2023$. Let's use that to figure out the day of the week for $1$ January $2000$, $2100$, $2200$, and $2300$.

Since $1$ Jan $2000$, there have been $23\times365+6+31+28+31+30+31+30+31+2=8615=1230\times7+5$ days, so counting back from Wednesday, that day must have been a Saturday.

The hundred years to $1$ January $2100$ amount to $100\times365+25=36525=5217\times7+6$ days, so $1$ Jan $2100$ should be a Friday.

From $1$ Jan $2100$ to $1$ Jan $2200$ is $36524=5217\times7+5$ days, so $1$ Jan $2200$ should be a Wednesday. And, similarly, $1$ Jan $2300$ should be a Monday.

So options A and C are incorrect, since it can be a Monday, and B is incorrect, since it can be a Friday, while D is the correct answer, since it can't be a Sunday and it can't be a Tuesday.

Comment: @peter, I completely missed that. That rules out the years in the $2200$ and $2300$ line, leaving only the $2100$ line (e.g., $2500=50^2$, $4900=70^2$, and so on). So we're back to my original comment from when the question was first posted; B is the only incorrect answer.